# How to Keep ArrayList Value When Changing Activity in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, arraylist

This is ViewActivity

```
public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView lvPerson;
    private PersonListAdapter adapter;
    public List<Person> mPersonList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);

        lvPerson = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        //Add new person
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.hasExtra("add")){
            String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
            String email = intent.getStringExtra("email");
            String address = intent.getStringExtra("address");
            mPersonList.add(new Person(name, email, address));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data berhasil ditambahkan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //Init adapter
        adapter = new PersonListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mPersonList);
        lvPerson.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

This is InputActivity

```
public class InputActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_input);
    }

    public void saveButtonClicked(View view){

        EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        EditText address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);

        String strName = name.getText().toString();
        String strEmail = email.getText().toString();
        String strAddress = address.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("add", true);
        intent.putExtra("name", strName);
        intent.putExtra("email", strEmail);
        intent.putExtra("address", strAddress);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Show my flow is when save button clicked in InputActivity, it will run "add person" code in ViewActivity and add data from form to ArrayList.

That's work, but when i changing activity using intent and i back to ViewActivity, ArrayList data gone.

What i want is to keep all value that i've already input in InputActivity.

Hope you understand what i mean :)

Comment: Do you want to preserve it indefinitely, or just within a single app session?

Comment: Only in a single app session

Comment: but the problem is when i start new activity, the ArrayList data gone. I'm so stack, i have no idea with android. btw, this is my school task. this is the first time i learn Android @TylerV

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. There are a lot of good answers here about passing data back and forth between activities. I added one with a different approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some good answers here, but since you only want it to persist during one app session I'll add another approach, a singleton to hold the data:

```
class DataHolder {
    final List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>;

    private DataHolder() {}

    static DataHolder getInstance() {
        if( instance == null ) {
            instance = new DataHolder();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private static DataHolder instance;
}
```

In either activity (or any place in your app), you can access the person list with

```
List<Person> ppl = DataHolder.getInstance().people;
```

For example, you would replace

```
public List<Person> mPersonList = new ArrayList<>();
```

with

```
// not sure why that was public...
private List<Person> mPersonList = DataHolder.getInstance().people;
```

It will only last for your current app session, but if you wanted to save them in the future you could add a backend database to the DataHolder so that every time you added a person it was automatically saved somewhere.

Comment: Brilliant!! this is totally works and very simple. big thanks from me. you save my live from getting D score :)

Answer (score 3):

Override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) in InputActivity to save whatever data you want then override  onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) in the same activity to get the values back. Using Bundle, you can store pretty much any data that you want. I'd recommend something like this:

```
public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView lvPerson;
private PersonListAdapter adapter;
public List<Person> mPersonList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override 
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) { 
    outState.putStringArrayList("mPersonList", mPersonList); //I assume you want to mPersonList
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.mPersonList = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("mPersonList"); //on coming back retrieve all values using key
        }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);

    lvPerson = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    //Add new person
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.hasExtra("add")){
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        String email = intent.getStringExtra("email");
        String address = intent.getStringExtra("address");
        mPersonList.add(new Person(name, email, address));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data berhasil ditambahkan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //Init adapter
    adapter = new PersonListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mPersonList);
    lvPerson.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

Comment: The problem is in ViewActivity when i add the data to ArrayList. I'ts added, but when i changing activity the data will gone

Comment: Then you should override these two added method in ViewActivity. Let me show you how.

Comment: But i use "List<Person>" when declare ArrayList "public List<Person> mPersonList = new ArrayList<>();" it's give me error. Do you knom how to fix that?

Comment: Dear @DimasAdiAndrea List is an interface, ArrayList is a class that implements List, among several other interfaces(ArrayList class also implements Serializable, So I would recommend to use ArrayList

Comment: Moreever the main Idea is to override two methods to save data and retrieve it back. You can o tweaks to imlpement it as per your requirements

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is actually very very bad, since you're just creating Activity after Activity for each Person you want to add and create. It wastes memory and power.

Instead, what you should look for is simply to return the results from InputActivity back to ViewActivity.

In your ViewActivity, don't call `startActivity(intent)`, instead use `startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)`. Then override `onActivityResult()` so you can handle the results that are returned back to ViewActivity.

In InputActivity, don't call `startActivity()` instead, return the intent back to the ViewActivity.

An example of this is like so:

ViewActivity

```
public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView lvPerson;
    private PersonListAdapter adapter;
    public List<Person> mPersonList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);

        lvPerson = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        //Init adapter
        adapter = new PersonListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mPersonList);
        lvPerson.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String name = data.getStringExtra("name");
            String email = data.getStringExtra("email");
            String address = data.getStringExtra("address");
            mPersonList.add(new Person(name, email, address));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data berhasil ditambahkan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

InputActivity

```
public class InputActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_input);
    }

    public void saveButtonClicked(View view){

        EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        EditText address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);

        String strName = name.getText().toString();
        String strEmail = email.getText().toString();
        String strAddress = address.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("add", true);
        intent.putExtra("name", strName);
        intent.putExtra("email", strEmail);
        intent.putExtra("address", strAddress);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();    
    }
}
```

Doing it this way avoids recreating ViewActivity again so you don't have to recreate all the views and repopulate the lists. You simply reuse the existing ViewActivity and add the results to the existing list.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, your flow is the following:
1.) ViewActivity -> Intent -> InputActivity
2.) InputActivity -> Intent -> ViewActivity

If that is the case, you should read more about the "Activity Lifecycle" in Android:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

In short:
onCreate only gets called at the creation of the ViewActivity. If you go from there to the InputActivity and then back -> ViewActivity already exists and therefore oncreate does not get called.

One solution which comes to my mind for your case is startActivityForResult. Here an example on how to use it:
[How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Another general tip, as it seems that you are fairly new to android development: Use breakpoints and Log (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log) heavily to get a better feeling where and when things are happening. And do not only use tutorials to start development in Android. It does not hurt to read some beginners guide/book that explains some android specifics in more detail (like the Activity-Lifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize it as a string, using Gson/Jackson/or whatever, and then save it with `[SharedPreferences][1]`. And then in the new activity you just load it back from `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: While this would technically work, android already gives you the ability to save the state of and activity with `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`

Comment: he is trying to pass a class between two activities. At least this is what I have understood of his question, I might be wrong.