# I want so use a Database from different classes, how can I do that in JAVA? (AndroidStudio/Java)

Tags: java, android

Im struggling with the following problem:

I have to classes, MainClass and SecondClass.

In the MainClass I create a database (mDatabase) and I am inserting data 
to the database.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
public SQLDatabase dbHelper; //created class to initialize my database
public SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        dbHelper = new SQLDatabase(this);
        mDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        mDatabase.insert(....);
}
```

Now I want to display the data from the database (mDatabase) in a different Activity.
So, I have to use the variable mDatabase from another class, because I am using a recyclerView in a different Activity, this is why:

```
public class SecondActivity{

    public void onCreate(){
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mAdapter = new AdapterClass(this, getAllItems());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public Cursor getAllItems(){

    return mDatabase.query(....);
    }


}
```

I want to have one Activity where I type in data for the database, and I want to have a second Activity where I can display the inserted data.

Do you know how I can use the mDatabase from two classes?

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51344957/9473786)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Keep ArrayList Value When Changing Activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344683/how-to-keep-arraylist-value-when-changing-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Open a new database connection in the other activity.

Variables and objects cannot be shared between activities unless they are `static` (and compatible with that use case: objects that need an Activity Context will cause problems and leaks if made static), or `Serializable` and you provide it as a parameter.

You can also consider **Fragments**: that will allow to create the `mDatabase` connection in your containing `Activity` and reuse it from your `Fragments`, or place the Database connection at the Application Level, if the database connection can be initialized with an Application context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this solution and will let you know, if it helped me.

Comment: Thanks for you help, your comment. Could you give me an example code?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your own Application class.

```java
    public class TestApplication extends Application { 

            public static SQLDatabase dbHelper; 
            public static SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                super.onCreate();
                initDb();
            }

            public void initDb() {
                dbHelper = new SQLDatabase(this);
            mDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            mDatabase.insert(....);
            }

            public static SQLiteDatabase getDb()  {
                return mDatabase;
            }
        }
```

2. Add you Application class to AndroidManifest under Application tag

   `<application android:name="TestApplication"`
3. Use it from your activities:

   `TestApplication.getDb()`

If it helped please mark as answered :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this solution and will let you know, if it helped me.

Comment: I got a question to number 3. Dont you think, that you have to create an object from the class Testapplication first? Your trying to use a method directly from a class.

Comment: Thanks man, I figured it out with your help. I appreciate it. Because its a static method I dont have to create an object from the class. With this solution I am able to build my app in seperate activities.

Comment: Glad to here that :)