# How to take a variable that received the Intent, make it static, and send it to another class on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I created an object of the Intent class called receiverIntent, to receive a variable from the previous class:

```
Intent receiverIntent = getIntent();
```

Then I created a variable called completeName, to receive a variable called "name", through an Intent:

```
    String completeName = receiverIntent.getStringExtra("name");
```

But I want to send this completeName variable to another class without needing to use Intent.
For that I tried using public static. But error happens.
It Displays the following error in the receiverIntent object:
"Non-static field receiverIntent cannot be referenced from a static context": https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/UHWNTaY

Please, how can I make the completeName variable as being public and static so that another class can recognize this variable called completeName without an error?

Comment: If you want a simple solution, you could just make a [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344683/how-to-keep-arraylist-value-when-changing-activity-in-android/51344957#51344957)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a `complete name` value to another activity/class you can do it with same approach as you did in this example. Put name in the intent extras and extract it when another activity/class is launched.